# Is there a verb in "Possibly the more possible possibility."?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I uttered the phrase "Possibly the more possible possibility." and wondered whether or not there was a verb in it, and therefore, whether or not it was actually a sentence at all?

Did I mean "It is possibly the more possible possibility." and, therfore, the verb is "is" or "to be"?

Comment: General Reference - obviously there's no verb, any more than there would be if OP had gone for some less ludicrous rephrasing such as *"Perhaps the more plausible possibility"*. The concept of "a sentence" is too vague to address anyway, but OP might think the label applied better if his "noun phrase" were preceded by *"This scenario **is**..."*

Comment: The copula is the verb, grasshopper.

Comment: Only *you* can tell us what you meant.

Comment: I'm quite offended that this question has been closed as *too basic*. What is basic for you, might not be basic to someone else. I'm a Mathematician and software developer; English is not my primary concern in life. This question has been answered very well below and I learnt something.

Comment: Hi Alex, as per the [faq], this site is for "linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts". If English isn't of particular concern to you, maybe this isn't the site you're looking for.

Comment: @MattЭллен Ouch.  That's not a very community-building statement.  Per the FAQ, this question seems to me to be a grammar/word choice and usage question, which is listed under the "topics are welcomed here" heading.  The "simple and basic" criteria leave some room for interpretation, though.

Comment: @Zoot — then your reading comprehension is different to mine. The way I read it, Alex's asking us to tell him what he meant. I was trying to be level headed in my comment, but people who come here and admit they don't care about English get my hackles up.

Comment: @MattЭллен  I guess so.  My interpretation of the question was how to find the implied verbs in a spoken sentence fragment, which was answered well by Noah and Daniel.  Perhaps some editing could clean up the question enough to merit re-opening.

Comment: @MattЭллен "English is not my primary concern" is completely different to "I don't care about English". I am English! Of course, I care about English (and the fact most people can't use it).

Comment: @Zoot Your interpretation was correct. The question was about implied verbs.

Comment: Are you thinking that it might be _another_ implied verb like 'There went a possible...' or 'I have a possible...'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implying "It is..."  and I would call it a sentence if the context surrounding it made the subject obvious.  Written English has lots of sentences with implied subjects, but not very many with implied verbs.

Imperative sentences (like "Go away.") often imply the subject (in this case "You").

Comment: Or *Thank you*, which has an implied *I*.  Another term for this is *[ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))*.

Comment: @Danielδ: Though one can certainly analyze it this way, I don't think there is _necessarily_ an implied 'I'. What about 'thanks.' or 'yes' or 'hello'? They stand on their own.